# SQLite database file created from JDBC?

Tags: database, sqlite, jdbc, using

I have created a SQLite database from Java. Now I want to know where it is stored physically on disk, so that I can push that file on to Android.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You specified a database name as part of the JDBC connection URL. Look for a file with that name on your harddisk. Example:

```
jdbc:sqlite:test.db
```

-> look for `test.db`

Answer (score 1):

SQLite usually produces one file with the extension .sqlite, but this is just convention, the extension can be anything.

As already was said, the code which opens the database spefifies the path where the file should be stored, so you have to look there.

Comment: Thank you. Since I am not providing any path, the database was created at the package's location. :-)